# Spring-boot inbuilt tomcat server not starting

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am building a very basic spring-boot service using the inbuild tomcat server.

Pom looks like this :

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>-->


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am setting the port in the `application.properties` file as `server.port=8089`. There is one Ping URI added in the controller class as :

```
@RequestMapping("/ping")
@RestController
public class helloController {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World Spring-boot app", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I do a `mvn clean package` everything works fine and the build is a success. But when I run the application from the `Main()` this is what the log looks like :

```
2017-09-19 10:37:32.219  INFO 6436 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-09-19 10:37:32.290  INFO 6436 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77f99a05: startup date [Tue Sep 19 10:37:32 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-19 10:37:33.782  INFO 6436 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-09-19 10:37:33.802  INFO 6436 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.043 seconds (JVM running for 2.802)
2017-09-19 10:37:33.802  INFO 6436 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@77f99a05: startup date [Tue Sep 19 10:37:32 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-09-19 10:37:33.802  INFO 6436 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

The log is not showing what port the service is starting .

What else is to be done to start the service on the designated port and to keep the server up an running?

Comment: For starters, remove the `spring-web` dependency. Remove the compiler plugin and re0-add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Also how do you run the `main` method? Commandline? IDE? Or?...

Comment: @M.Deinum - As per your suggestion re-added the spring-boot-maven -plugin and started the server this time by , **spring-boot:start** option. Now in the log I do see the application starting on port 8089 but again the server stops itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. Started the in built tomcat server using spring-boot:run option